# it says apk installed but no apk

Tags: java, android, xml

I made my schedule. I'm installing but the apk is not there. everything is clear in the picture

I made changes to the manifest, is it something related to it?

[image]

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </activity></intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".guzelsozleractivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring **MainActivity** twice.

Declare it like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest was wrongly entered, update the `Manifest.xml` to the code given below it will work. Please like and accept the answer if it worked.

Happy coding.

```
         <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: This gave an error. The code below worked fine. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything different from the below code @Cebom25